# Kivy Window configure error - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'top'

Tags: kivy, window

I have a kivy gui I've made on one machine that has python3.7, but on another machine running python 3.9 I'm getting errors on the exact same code.

The code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.top = 30
Window.left = 10
screen_width = 700
screen_height = 775
Window.size = (screen_width, screen_height)
print(f"new window size: {Window.size}")
Config.write()
```

The error occurs on the first Window.size line.
The error:

```
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'top'
```

I've tried to find if there's a compatibility issue between 3.7 and 3.9 but I haven't found anything in the documentation that hints to that. Is there an install I'm missin?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly have an error before that indicating `unable to find any window provider at all` and before that, errors indicating what went wrong with the window providers available to your platforms. Otherwise `Window` wouldn't be `None`.

Please try to have the `sdl2` window provider working, or give the error preventing that from happening, to get help on that.

Comment: The other user sent me the full error, and it did include this:
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: The specified module could not be found

I'm new to gui development, sorry. Is this a package I need to install?